# "Unexpected string literal" error with backtick in SQL query within Python bigquery API

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I am trying to loop through tables in my BigQuery dataset and perform a SQL query and export the table results. I get an error when trying to include the table name in the for loop.

```
for i in range(0, 3):
  dataset_id = 'test_dataset'
  tabelname = "test"+ str(i) 
  tableOutName = tabelname + "_cleaned"

  job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

  # Set the destination table
  table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(tableOutName)
  job_config.destination = table_ref
  sql = "\"\"\"" + " SELECT * FROM " + "`my-bucket-name.{}.{}` ".format(dataset_id, tabelname) +  "WHERE SAFE.ST_GeogFromText(WKT) IS NOT NULL " +"\"\"\""

  # Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
  query_job = client.query(
      sql,
      location='EU',
      job_config=job_config)  # API request - starts the query

  query_job.result()  # Waits for the query to finish
  print('Query results loaded to table {}'.format(table_ref.path))
```

Comment: This `"\"\"\""` looks suspicious. First it could be easier written as `'"""'`. Second I doubt that those quotation marks should be part of the query string.

Comment: Can you also printout the Sql object so we can see how it actually looks after the concat logic? I suggest to take this Sql to BQ webUI and test it

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The '"""' does not seem to work. And the query definitely runs when I test it in the BG webUI. This is what the SQL object should look like: """ SELECT * FROM `my-bucket-name.test.test0` WHERE SAFE.ST_GeogFromText(WKT) IS NOT NULL """

Comment: I am essentially trying to implement the example on this page under "Creating a table from a query result" except applying it within a for loop: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables

Comment: In the example the triple quotation marks are [delimiters for the string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) in Python code, not part of the string itself.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthias, that solves it. My unfamiliarity with Python was clearly the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The use for triple quotation mark in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables) are [delimiters for the string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) in Python code, and not part of the string itself.

Therefore, the following code line has to be changed accordingly:

```
  sql = "\"\"\"" + " SELECT * FROM " + "`my-bucket-name.{}.{}` ".format(dataset_id, tabelname) +  "WHERE SAFE.ST_GeogFromText(WKT) IS NOT NULL " +"\"\"\""
```

The documentation uses it this way:

```
sql = """
SELECT corpus
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
GROUP BY corpus;
"""
```